# how to add values of related rows to a column in SQL

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a table with contract information and I would like to add a calculated column that identifies when a contract is consecutive to the previous one of the same client. So when the end date of a contract matches the start date of the following one for the same client we consider that is consecutive.

The data looks like this:

[image]

And I would like it to look like this:

[image]

I tried doing an inner join of the contract table with itself and then I unioned it, but I don't think that is the most effective way of doing it.

Do you know of a better way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add in- and output as text rather than an image.

Comment: You should use views instead of trying to calculate something on existing table. What if there is more than one contract related to a line? You basicly have many2many datamodel here and it is hard to make as a one column.

Comment: Would you create a view with only the consecutive contracts then? To do so would you still do it with the inner join and the union?

Comment: I'm not sure I like your "related contract" idea. What if there are three consecutive contracts? Is the middle one listed as related to the previous contract or the next one? I'd suggest you either want to split this into two columns ("previous related" and "next related") or to find a different approach.

Comment: I don't know _Presto_ but `LEAD` and `LAG` _may_ be useful functions. See https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html

Comment: I created this _SQL Server_ (not _Presto_) Fiddle. Had to change `31st June` to `30th June` since the former is not a valid date! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/13fc30/10/0

Comment: @Barryblp . . . What if you had three or four clients in a row?  What would the results look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below was tested on *SQL Server*, but may also work on *Presto*. *SQL Server* has `bit` values rather than `boolean`s, so I've returned `TRUE` and `FALSE` as strings. Hopefully you'll be able to make any necessary modifications.

```
SELECT
  c.contract_id
  ,c.client
  ,c.start_date
  ,c.end_date
  ,CASE
       WHEN LAG(c.end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client ORDER BY c.start_date) = c.start_date
       THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE'
   END as is_consecutive
  ,CASE
       WHEN LAG(c.end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client ORDER BY c.start_date) = c.start_date
       THEN LAG(c.contract_id) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client ORDER BY c.start_date)
   END as related_previous
  ,CASE
       WHEN LEAD(c.start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client ORDER BY c.start_date) = c.end_date
       THEN LEAD(c.contract_id) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client ORDER BY c.start_date)
   END as related_next
FROM
  contract c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked nicely. I will add the related_previous and related_next.

Answer (score 1):

Your "related ids" is a challenge if there are more than 2.  That turns this into a gaps-and-islands problem, best approach using `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(prev_end_date = end_date, false) as is_consecutive,
       array_agg(contract_id) over (partition by clent, grp order by start_date) as contracts
from (select sum(case when prev_end_date = end_date then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by client order by start_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (partition by client order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Note:  This puts all related contracts into an array.  You can remove the current contract, if you like.